How to detect if function is called from interrupt handler on RiscV
Dears. I am writing a code in C for RiscV (Microchip PolarFire MPFS). There is a C function that must do additional actions if it is called from an interrupt handler. However, these actions should not be performed if the function is called from the main code.
Note that everything runs in m-mode in the current version of the code.
mcause.interrupt may look it does exactly that I need but it doesn't. As I understood in the deeper look, mcause.interrupt can be used in the handler to detect if the handler is called because of an interrupt or because of an exception. However, it represents a different problem. I found that sometimes, mcause.interrupt is set even the main code is running.
Please, do not waste your and mine time asking "What do you need it for?" and trying to advise me a workaround. I know what I need, I know why do I need it and I know how to make a workaround.

Pass a parameter to the function to indicate whether called by the main thread or otherwise?

I don't think you're supposed to look at mcause unless you're in the handler, which is to say I suspect it is essentially undefined rather than specifically set somehow for non-handlers to look at.

Sorry I did not define the problem well. The named C function must detect if it is run from ISR. It is requirement. Usage of a parameter to indicate it is not acceptable. I search for a method how to do it.

"Usage of a parameter to indicate it is not acceptable." — why is that?

Another approach might be to duplicate the function using one only for call by the interrupt handler and the other only for call outside of interrupt handler.  Then that function will know by definition.  If the call stack is fairly deep, then make an outer function like this that sets a thread local variable that others can check.

Dear Erik. It is nice you search for same answer. However I really need to know if there is some flag that indicates that MCU processes ISR at the moment. For example, I work with ARM cortex M3 and it has that. Only if I am 100% sure it is not possible on RISC-V, I can use something other. There are various options I can think up myself. Sure, I can use additional parameter or duplicate the function, those are simple and straightforward ideas which occur to anybody.
